# Eloquent group by and count

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, count, eloquent

My query concerns 1 table: 'entries'. The SQL query that works fine is:

```
select `type`, YEAR(`date`) AS import_year, count(*) as aantal from
`entries`  where `merk` = 'FORD' and `date` <> `other_date`
GROUP BY `type`, YEAR(`date`)
```

This query gives following result:

> - FOCUS 1998 13
> - FOCUS 2001 15
> - ORION 2007 12
> - ORION 2009 7

But now the issue is how to arrange this in Laravel/Eloquent, with preferably one statement.
Until now:

```
    $registrations = entry::where('merk', 'FORD')
            ->whereRaw('date <> other_date')
            ->selectRaw('type, YEAR(date) AS import_year')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('type_final', 'import_year')
```

But this delivers me all individual entries that meet the requirements, and I only want to have the counted items. I tried a lot, but cannot get the final solution in a simple way. Could some help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `get()` after `groupBy()`:

```php
$registrations = entry::where('merk', 'FORD')
        ->whereRaw('date <> other_date')
        ->selectRaw('type, YEAR(date) AS import_year, count(*) AS aantal')
        ->groupBy('type', 'import_year')
        ->get()
```

Comment: Thnx, this one did the job

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve aggregates (`count` in your case). See this section in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models